# Не могу разобраться с результатом парсинга библиотеки PapaParse

Tags: javascript

1. Есть файл формата CSV

```
1-я строка - заголовок (ключи)
...
остальные строки - данные (значения)
```

2. Для парсинга файла использую библиотеку [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/). Фрагмент кода из библиотеки:

```js
// Затем записываем данные
for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
  var maxCol = hasHeader ? fields.length : data[row].length;

  var emptyLine = false;
  var nullLine = hasHeader ? Object.keys(data[row]).length === 0 : data[row].length === 0;
  if (skipEmptyLines && !hasHeader) {
    emptyLine = skipEmptyLines === 'greedy' ? data[row].join('').trim() === '' : data[row].length === 1 && data[row][0].length === 0;
  }
  if (skipEmptyLines === 'greedy' && hasHeader) {
    var line = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < maxCol; c++) {
      var cx = dataKeyedByField ? fields[c] : c;
      line.push(data[row][cx]);
    }
    emptyLine = line.join('').trim() === '';
  }

  if (!emptyLine) {
    for (var col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
      if (col > 0 && !nullLine)
        csv += _delimiter;
      var colIdx = hasHeader && dataKeyedByField ? fields[col] : col;
      csv += safe(data[row][colIdx], col);
    }
    if (row < data.length - 1 && (!skipEmptyLines || (maxCol > 0 && !nullLine))) {
      csv += _newline;
    }
  }
}
return csv;
}
```

3. Результат работы библиотеки (взят из консоли):

```
Arguments
0: {…}

data: (9) […]
0: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:18", VarValue: "0", … }
1: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:23", VarValue: "0", … }
2: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:28", VarValue: "0", … }
3: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:33", VarValue: "0", … }
4: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:38", VarValue: "0", … }
5: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:44", VarValue: "0", … }
6: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:49", VarValue: "0", … }
7: Object { VarName: "DI_valve_opened", TimeString: "29.05.2019 16:42:54", VarValue: "0", … }
8: Object { VarName: "" }
length: 9           ​​​
<prototype>: Array []
            ​​
errors: Array [ {…} ]
meta: Object { delimiter: ";", linebreak: "\r\n", aborted: false, … }
<prototype>: Object { … };
```

4. Хочу вывести в консоль значения по ключу `VarValue`. Моя ошибка заключается в том, что не правильно указываю свойство `data.VarValue`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Arguments.data.VarValue.length-1; i++) {
  // if (Arguments.data.VarValue[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  //i = индекс
  //значение = Arguments.data.VarValue[i]
  console.log("Элемент массива[ "+ i +" ] = " + Arguments.data.VarValue[i]);  
}
```

5. Хочу, чтобы выводилось в консоли так:

```
Элемент массива [0] = Значение 1;
Элемент массива [1] = Значение 2;
Элемент массива [2] = Значение 3;
```

Вот функция, которая выводит массив объектов в консоль:

```
function completeFn()
{
    end = performance.now();
    if (!$('#stream').prop('checked')
            && !$('#chunk').prop('checked')
            && arguments[0]
            && arguments[0].data)
        rows = arguments[0].data.length;

    console.log("Finished input (async). Time:", end-start, arguments);

    console.log("Rows:", rows, "Stepped:", stepped, "Chunks:", chunks);

}
```

Если я изменю строку:

```
console.log("Finished input (async). Time:", end-start, arguments);
```

На строку:

```
console.log("Элемент массива", arguments[0].data[0].VarValue);
```

То в консоли выводится необходимое значение. Теперь надо, чтобы прочитались все значения `arguments[0].data[i].VarValue`

Добавляю код:

```
  for(let i=0;i<arguments.data[i].length;i++)
    {console.log("Элемент массива["+i+"]="+arguments.data[i].VarValue);}
```

Консоль ругается на неизвестность arguments.

Comment: а почему `for`, а не `foreach`?

Comment: Рустам, данный Вами материал прочту. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что данный пример позволит вам понять, что происходит и как работать с результатом парсинга.

```js
// Элемент для выбора файлов.
const INPUT = document.querySelector('input[name="readable"]');

// Элемент для вывода сгенерированной таблицы.
const PREVIEW = document.querySelector('#preview');

// Регулярное выражение для проверки расширения файла.
const REGEX = new RegExp('(.*?)\.(csv)$', 'i');

// Настройки для плагина PapaParse.
// https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config
const CONFIG = {

}

// Регистрируем функцию обработчика события `change`,
// срабатывающего при изменении элемента выбора файла.
INPUT.addEventListener('change', handleFile);

// Функция, отрабатывающая при выборе файла.
function handleFile(event) {
  // Выбираем первый файл из списка файлов.
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  // Если файл выбран и его расширение допустимо,
  // то читаем его содержимое и отправляем
  // в функцию отрисовки таблицы.
  if (file && REGEX.test(file.name)) {
    // Парсим содержимое файла
    // при помощи библиотеки PapaParse.
    // https://www.papaparse.com/docs#results
    Papa.parse(file, {
      complete: function(results) {
        // console.log(results);
        // Массив данных.
        const data = results.data;
        // Массив ошибок.
        const errors = results.errors;
        // Объект с дополнительной информацией
        const meta = results.meta;

        // Отправляем полученные данные
        // на отрисовку таблицы.
        renderTable(data);
      }
    }, CONFIG);
  } else {
    // Мизерная обработка ошибок.
    alert('Файл не выбран либо его формат не поддерживается.');
    event.target.value = '';
  }
}

// Функция отрисовки таблицы.
function renderTable(data) {
  // Предварительно создадим элементы,
  // отвечающие за каркас таблицы.
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  const thead = document.createElement('thead');
  const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // Добавим класс к таблице.
  table.classList.add('table');

  // Перебираем полученный массив.
  data.forEach(function(row, index) {
    // Создадим элемент строки для таблицы.
    const trow = document.createElement('tr');

    // Перебираем полученный массив будущих ячеек.
    row.forEach(function(cell) {
      // Создадим элемент ячейки для таблицы.
      const tcell = document.createElement(index > 0 ? 'td' : 'th');
      // Заполним содержимое ячейки.
      tcell.textContent = cell;
      // Добавляем ячейку к родительской строке.
      trow.appendChild(tcell);
    });

    // Добавляем строку к родительскому элементу.
    // Если индекс строки больше нуля,
    // то родительский элемент - `tbody`,
    // в противном случае- `thead`.
    index > 0 ? tbody.appendChild(trow) : thead.appendChild(trow);
  });

  // Добавляем заголовок таблицы к родительскому элементу.
  table.appendChild(thead);
  // Добавляем тело таблицы к родительскому элементу.
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  // Очищаем элемент для вывода таблицы.
  PREVIEW.innerHTML = '';
  // Добавляем саму таблицу к родительскому элементу.
  PREVIEW.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="file" name="readable" accept=".csv" />

  <div id="preview"></div>
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.0.2/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```